# JSON file cannot be de-serialized

Tags: json, database, vb.net

I am trying to use JSON script and getting error;

I have managed to deserialized JSON with single array in the row, but this script has multiple arrays in single row.

My Code;

```
Dim s As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\sajid\source\repos\JSON_TO_DATABASE\dummy.json") 'reader.ReadToEnd '
Dim myJs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(s)
```

https://i.ibb.co/7XRyhzk/Error.png (Error Massage)

I need this below JSON to deserialize so that i can use the data in my application and later save it to database

JSON script here;

```
{"SuccessResponse": {
  "Head": {
    "RequestId": "0b1192a115701283055003672e6b47",
    "RequestAction": "GetOrder",
    "ResponseType": "Order",
    "Timestamp": "2019-10-03T23:45:05+05:00"
  },
  "Body": {
    "Orders": [
      {
        "OrderId": 103726686259125,
        "CustomerFirstName": "ABC",
        "CustomerLastName": "",
        "OrderNumber": 103125,
        "PaymentMethod": "COD",
        "Remarks": "",
        "DeliveryInfo": "",
        "Price": "800.00",
        "GiftOption": false,
        "GiftMessage": "",
        "VoucherCode": "",
        "CreatedAt": "2019-05-24 11:30:45",
        "UpdatedAt": "2019-06-10 17:25:51",
        "AddressBilling": {
          "FirstName": "CBD",
          "LastName": "",
          "Phone": "92HJHJ2",
          "Phone2": "",
          "Address1": "Pakistan",
          "Address2": "",
          "Address3": "Punjab",
          "Address4": "Lahore",
          "Address5": "H",
          "CustomerEmail": "",
          "City": "Lahore",
          "PostCode": "",
          "Country": "Pakistan",
          "TreeAddressId": ""
        },
        "AddressShipping": {
          "FirstName": "BCD",
          "LastName": "",
          "Phone": "923UJII102",
          "Phone2": "",
          "Address1": "Pakistan",
          "Address2": "",
          "Address3": "Punjab",
          "Address4": "Lahore",
          "Address5": "H",
          "CustomerEmail": "",
          "City": "Lahore",
          "PostCode": "",
          "Country": "Pakistan",
          "TreeAddressId": ""
        },
        "NationalRegistrationNumber": "",
        "ItemsCount": 4,
        "PromisedShippingTimes": "",
        "ExtraAttributes": "",
        "Statuses": [
          "failed"
        ],
        "Voucher": 75.00,
        "ShippingFee": 99.00,
        "TaxCode": "",
        "BranchNumber": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}}
```

My Class Model

```
Public Class Rootobject
        Public Property SuccessResponse As Successresponse
    End Class

    Public Class Successresponse
        Public Property Head As Head
        Public Property Body As Body
    End Class

    Public Class Head
        Public Property RequestId As String
        Public Property RequestAction As String
        Public Property ResponseType As String
        Public Property Timestamp As Date
        Public Property TotalCount As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Body
        Public Property Orders() As List(Of Order)
        Public Property Addressbillings() As List(Of Addressbilling)
        Public Property Addressshippings() As List(Of Addressshipping)

    End Class

    Public Class Order
        Public Property OrderId As Long
        Public Property CustomerFirstName As String
        Public Property CustomerLastName As String
        Public Property OrderNumber As Long
        Public Property PaymentMethod As String
        Public Property Remarks As String
        Public Property DeliveryInfo As String
        Public Property Price As String
        Public Property GiftOption As Boolean
        Public Property GiftMessage As String
        Public Property VoucherCode As String
        Public Property CreatedAt As String
        Public Property UpdatedAt As String
        Public Property AddressBilling As Addressbilling
        Public Property AddressShipping As Addressshipping
        Public Property NationalRegistrationNumber As String
        Public Property ItemsCount As Integer
        Public Property PromisedShippingTimes As String
        Public Property ExtraAttributes As String
        Public Property Statuses() As String
        Public Property Voucher As Single
        Public Property ShippingFee As Single
        Public Property TaxCode As String
        Public Property BranchNumber As String
    End Class

    Public Class Addressbilling
        Public Property FirstName As String
        Public Property LastName As String
        Public Property Phone As String
        Public Property Phone2 As String
        Public Property Address1 As String
        Public Property Address2 As String
        Public Property Address3 As String
        Public Property Address4 As String
        Public Property Address5 As String
        Public Property CustomerEmail As String
        Public Property City As String
        Public Property PostCode As String
        Public Property Country As String
        Public Property TreeAddressId As String
    End Class

    Public Class Addressshipping
        Public Property FirstName As String
        Public Property LastName As String
        Public Property Phone As String
        Public Property Phone2 As String
        Public Property Address1 As String
        Public Property Address2 As String
        Public Property Address3 As String
        Public Property Address4 As String
        Public Property Address5 As String
        Public Property CustomerEmail As String
        Public Property City As String
        Public Property PostCode As String
        Public Property Country As String
        Public Property TreeAddressId As String
    End Class
```

Comment: You need to post the class structure (the Model) that you're using to deserialize your JSON. `Rootobject` here is undefined.

Comment: @Jimi I have posted my Class Model

Comment: @Jimi I know this is the problem in JSON script `"Statuses": [
          "failed"
        ],` but this is what i am getting through webAPI i dont want to modify it manully

Comment: Change `Public Property Statuses() As String` to `Public Property Statuses As List(Of String)`. In `Public Class Body`, (though not strictly necessary) remove the parenteses (e.g., `Public Property Orders() As List(Of Order)` to `Public Property Orders As List(Of Order)`)

Comment: @Jimi You are great... Thanks for the support.

Comment: @Jimi not necessary but it will be great if you tell me that why we have to remove the parenteses after Orders, just for information

Comment: That kind of syntax is supported but it's not the current standard. It may not be supported in the future. About the Properties' names *case*, since the answer mentions it: in VB.Net a case mismatch is *tolerated*. It may not be in `C#`. Better decorate properties with a `[JsonProperty("PropertyName")]` to redefine a member's name.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% but an initial look I notice your class is not camel-casing certain things

```
Public Class Addressshipping
Public Class Addressbilling
```

Where the json is camel cased

```
"AddressShipping"
"AddressBilling"
SuccessResponse
```

I would look through both files to make sure that they're all the same.
For example your SuccessResponse:
`Public Property SuccessResponse As Successresponse`
vs

`Public Property Addressbillings() As List(Of Addressbilling)
Public Property Addressshippings() As List(Of Addressshipping)`

Comment: @Jimi I know this is the problem in JSON script `"Statuses": [
          "failed"
        ],` but this is what i am getting through webAPI i dont want to modify it manully

Comment: @Jimi - Everything else is fine if i am going to modify it from `"Statuses": [ "failed" ],` to `"Statuses": "failed",` every thing turns fine but as this is webAPI i dont want to manually modify it,